# Нумерация вершин графа в pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Дан ориентированный граф. Он полностью отрисован в pictureBox. Мне необходимо пронумеровать вершины графа, они выглядят как точки. Заранее количество вершин не известно, поэтому label не подходит.

Можно это как-то сделать?
Код как задаются вершины:

```
int n = dataGridView1.RowCount; //количество вершин, переменная
double alfa = 360 / n;
List<float> X = new List<float>();
List<float> Y = new List<float>();

for (double i = 0; i < 360; i = i + alfa)
{
    double x = 120 * Math.Cos(i) + 200;
    X.Add(Convert.ToSingle(x));
    double y = 120 * Math.Sin(i) + 200;
    Y.Add(Convert.ToSingle(y));
}

SolidBrush t = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
for (int i = 0; i < X.Count; i++)
{
    gr.FillEllipse(t, X[i] - 7, Y[i] - 7, 10, 10);

    pictureBox1.Image = picture;
}
```

Comment: А что мешает создать label'ы в цикле?

Comment: [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext), [Graphics.DrawString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) - рисовать текст рядом с эллипсом

Comment: Для полной красоты можно еще посчитать вектор от точки вершины в сторону медианы наибольшего угла между линиями, отсчитать по вектору нужное расстояние, и воткнуть по высчитанным координатам текст.